# Is 2kg static cross-load dangerous for a carbon frame?

Tags: carbon, bags

The bicycle is a carbon fiber cross-country machine. It is from a local manufacturer, not a well known one.

Compared to other CF bikes but for more aggressive riding, when I knock on the tubes it feels that the wall thickness is half of the others! Nevertheless, it handles it's purpose well.

I am contemplating is it safe to add a triangle bag with a multitool, tube, oil, rag. <sub><TODO: I have the bag, just equip it and weigh it> <TODO: add picture></sub> Intended application: cross country with rock gardens and drops below one meter. My worry is that the bag is going to load the top tube radially. And the end strap is at the middle of the tube where it's certainly weakest.

Comment: It should be fine. The top tube has to handle the force of you landing drops and stuff, so another few kg radially won’t hurt anything. I must ask: why do you need to carry oil with you?

Comment: @MaplePanda I am worried because the loading of "drops and stuff" is axial on all tubes. The bag would be a radial load and I've heard CF is non-istropic. Now thinking of it, the very shape of the top tube is intended to stand axial loads.

Comment: Can’t you ask the manufacturer? At least for road bikes a “use case” all frames have to survive is the rider sitting (or rather “lounging”) on the top tube. So I’d think that a 2kg mass firmly attached to the top tube wouldn’t be an issue at all.

Comment: @MaplePanda Vorac is right, the direction and location of the force has a strong influence on how much force can be endured without breaking. Especially a perpendicular force right in the middle of the tube has the potential to provide the additional bending that's needed to break the tube under compression. I have no experience with carbon frames, so I won't answer, but the worry is very well justified.

Comment: A not unknown accident on an XC bike ...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glU-ZoJssjA  - no frame manufacturer would ship a frame that failed under this loading. A tube bag is minor in comparison!!!

Comment: I would be more worried about the straps rubbing and essentially sawing through the carbon with so much vibrations more than the overall force.

Comment: @MaplePanda I carry oil in my road toolkit, which I also use for long MTB rides. The oil is decanted into a 5ml dropper bottle (cheap on eBay).  That's enough for 2-3 chains; the other main use is if cleats start to feel stiff. But (on road) it's not unknown for me to ride 300km in almost unbroken rain

Comment: Any reason for a triangle bag and not a saddlebag?

Comment: @ChrisH I have tried about 5 saddlebags from different reputable manufacturers. For some reason they all failed within months, while triangle bags haven't.

Comment: @Vorac interesting.  I have an old BikeHut (own brand from Halfords, a not very good bike shop) on the MTB, that works fine, but needs a cable tie to keep it on the saddle rails.  On the tourer (sometimes borrowed for the MTB) I have a 15l Topeak.  That's had a little repair where a saddle bolt wore through the fabric, but I haven't come across a complete failure

Comment: @Vorac Is it perfectly axial though? Take a ruler and compress it from both ends: it will bow out towards one side. I agree with Criggie: unless this is some 800g Uber-lightweight frame, there better be enough excess material in all directions for 2kg to not be a problem.

Comment: @Chris H Ah okay, that’s totally understandable. I was trying to imagine what could possibly add up to 2kg, and somehow I got the idea that Vorac was carrying a half liter of chain oil or something ridiculous like that.

Comment: @MaplePanda I know people carry the 50-100ml bottles chain oil is sold in, but my tool kit weighs 800g plus pump, 2nd tube, and spare brake pads that are separate - probably 1kg in total

Answer (score 3):

Opinion, but a frame bag won't cause any problem for a normal bike frame.  If it were an ultralight hillclimbing bike with no paint or something specialist, then I'd worry.

If you're concerned about fretting of straps on the clear coat, get some of those clear frame-protection stickers and apply to the frame under any retention straps for your bag.  Also cinch velcro straps down firmly.

Comment: Agree completely. I'll add a recommendation to get generic 3M "clear helicopter tape" for the frame protection as you'll be able to purchase 10x the material for 0.5x the price compared to something branded for cycling.

Comment: Clear frame protection is expensive, just use duct tape.

Comment: @mattnz $10 will cover your entire frame, and the loss in resale value you get by slapping duct tape on your frame is worth much more than that.

Comment: I did the opposite - I made frame bags and sewed a length of soft cotton or velvet in where the strap goes.  So when its tight on the frame, the contact is padded.  Or you can use softer velcro.   Its even possible to use rivnuts and bolt the bag to the frame, though this is overdoing it to eleven !

Comment: @ChrisH I prefer a small frame bag, mounted in the nose of the front triangle, because it moves weight forward (helps me on climbs) and I can access it while riding (carefully).

Comment: @MaplePanda If you ever intend to sell your bike. There is also extra value in a low resale value: It reduces the likelihood of theft. If you do not intend to sell your bike ever, you are free to slap on any amount of duct tape, to customize it any way you want, and enjoy your bike for a longer time. Of course, that requires that you yourself don't fall for the looks of a shiny bike...